# android problem with SimpleDateFormat TimeZone

Tags: android, timezone, locale, simpledateformat

Let's consider this code sample:

```
DateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG, 
                    new Locale("ru", "RU"));
                 Date date = sdf.parse("8:13:05 PDT");
```

When I run this code on my desktop(java 1.6) all passes well, however on android devices I get exception, I think this is due to locale TimeZone:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 8:13:05 PDT
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot parse non-English date in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522347/cannot-parse-non-english-date-in-android)

Comment: These are two different issues

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe UNIX can parse the PDT timezone. I'm having the same issue. It can handle PST & PST8PDT, but not PDT. I believe the recommended solution is to use PST8PDT instead.